# How to use attributed placeholder in iOS with Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am having difficulty with the last argument in the function call..

```
        myTextField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Wage Type", attributes: NSForegroundColorAttributeName: ??????)
```

I am not sure how to set the colour of the placeholder using this method.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So the initializer you're using looks like this:

```
init(string aString: String!, attributes attributes: [NSObject : AnyObject]!)
```

It is expecting a dictionary mapping attribute keys to values. [Check out this document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html) to find the expected key/value pairings. So if all you want to do is change the text color, you could try this:

```
let attributesDictionary = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.greenColor()]
myTextField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Wage Type", attributes: attributesDictionary)
```

Let me know if you have any further questions regarding this!